# what is meant by Error % in jmeter(summary result)?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

1) I can not understand error % in summary result in Listeners.                  2) For example first time I've to run a test plan its error% is 90% and then run same test plan it shows 100% error. This error% is vary when i run my test plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error% denotes the percent of requests with errors.

100% error means all the requests sent from JMeter have failed.

You should add a Tree View Listener and then check the individual requests and responses. Such high percentage of error means that either your server is not available or all of your requests are invalid.

So you should use Tree View Listener in order to identify the actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Error % means how many requests failed or resulted in error throughout the test duration. Its calculated based on the #samples field.

2 and 3 Can you please give more details about your test plan? Like number of threads, ramp-up and duration.

Such high error percentage will need further analysis. Check if you have missed out correlation of some requests i.e. any dynamic values that are passed from one request to other or check for resource utilization of your target system if it can handle the load you are generating.

Comment: Thanks for Reply..My test plan is Thread user=100,Ramp-up= 5 sec. It shows 100% error and throughput=1.7/sec. Here server reply 100% of request is failed, then why should throughput is 1.7/sec.

Comment: @AnandhR, You need to look into your samplers (requests) and the parameters they are sending. That is where the issue is. You can analyze further by using Tree View listener. As rachna said you need to make sure that your requests are sending valid dynamic parameters. Especially you will need it in case you have any login steps in your scenario.

Comment: There is no login scenario in my test plan, There is only one http request am using for simply accessing the website only.

Comment: Check with single user if you are getting any errors. I would suggest you to increase the ramp-up in your case. In some cases socket connections are not established and may result in error. What is duration/iteration you are mentioning?@AnandhR